# How to check the balance accuracy between two texts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I tested some audio files for speech-to-text on IBM's Watson API and My own API.

for example,
text 1: got from IBM's Watson API.
text 2: got from own API.

I want to check the accuracy of text2 Relatively to text1.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not a good evaluation method because IBM Watson can have errors as well. You must have a gold-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO :)

As you may realize there are plenty of methods for measuring text similarity. Below I introduce two handy ones.

Using **Levenshtein** distance we can blindly determine the distance between two strings in terms of the number of char manipulation to change one for another. You can get it like this (installing `python-Levenshtein` would be necessary).

```
from Levenshtein import distance
yours = "got from the your own API."
IBM = "got from the IBM's Watson API"
distance(yours, IBM)
```

Using **BLEU** score you can determine similarity in a more semantically demanded way. This method would consider the overlap between `n-grams` so it's not doing it blindly.

```
import nltk
hypothesis = ['It', 'is', 'a', 'cat', 'at', 'room']
reference = ['It', 'is', 'a', 'cat', 'inside', 'the', 'room']
#there may be several references
BLEUscore = nltk.translate.bleu_score.sentence_bleu([reference], hypothesis)
print(BLEUscore)
```